# Artifactory Plugin Proxy Results in /v1/_ping: Bad Gateway

Tags: docker, jenkins-plugins, artifactory

Why do I get `/v1/_ping: Bad Gateway` errors when I follow the instructions for using [artifactory plugin with docker](https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Jenkins+Artifactory+Plugin+-+Setting+Up+Docker+Build+Info)?

1. jenkins 2.60.3 with Artifactory Plugin 2.12.2
2. `Enable Build-Info proxy for Docker images` on port 9999
3. jenkins `/var/lib/jenkins/secrets/jfrog/certs/jfrog.proxy.crt` added to $JAVA_HOME/jre/lib/security/cacerts on jenkins master and slave
4. jfrog nginx self sign cert added to $JAVA_HOME/jre/lib/security/cacerts on jenkins master and slave
5. access to jenkins:9999 open between hosts
6. `/etc/systemd/system/docker.service.d/http-proxy.conf` has contained the following with no difference to the tests

   [Service]
   Environment="HTTP_PROXY=http://jenkins:9999/"

   [Service]
   Environment="HTTPS_PROXY=https://jenkins:9999/"
7. Local docker test (`docker login 127.0.0.1:9999`) results in

`Error response from daemon: Login: Bad Request to URI: /v1/users/ (Code: 400; Headers: map[Content-Length:[30] Content-Type:[text/html; chars...`

8. Jenkins test results in `com.github.dockerjava.api.exception.BadRequestException: Bad Request to URI: /images/artifactory:<port>/hello-world:latest/json`

**Errors in Jenkins log**

```
SEVERE: (DISCONNECTED) [id: ..., L:0.0.0.0/0.0.0.0:... ! R:artifactory/...:5000]: 
Caught an exception on ProxyToServerConnection
io.netty.handler.codec.DecoderException: 
javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: General SSLEngine problem
...
Caused by: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building
 failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: 
 unable to find valid certification path to requested target
```

My virtual repo, its remote and local work when I don't use the jenkins proxy but according to the plugin docs I require jenkins proxy to get the build info I need to CI/CD promotion.

Answer (score 1):

Adding the certs to cacerts is somewhat less effective, if jenkins doesn't use that cert file.   I'm unsure if adding a cert to a store requires a restart in jenkins, but it does seem to be the case for tomcat so that's probably just how jenkins works.

1. Configure jenkins instance to use a private keystore [cloudbees doc on keystore](https://support.cloudbees.com/hc/en-us/articles/203821254-How-to-install-a-new-SSL-certificate-)
2. Copy $JENKINS_HOME/secrets/jfrog/certs/jfrog.proxy.crt to /etc/docker/certs.d/:/ca.crt
3. restart docker
4. Restart jenkins
5. test proxy via command line while tailing jenkins log - PASS

   `docker rmi artifactory:5000/hello-world:latest
   docker pull artifactory:5000/hello-world:latest`

This should use `/etc/systemd/system/docker.service.d/http-proxy.conf` HTTP_PROXY and go to jenkins proxy when then goes to the actual artifactory host.  The required keys should be found in the store so ssl handshake will be good and v2 api used.  If not, you'll see errors in jenkins.log

4. test helloworld on node via shell

   ```
   node("docker-experiments") {
   withCredentials([usernamePassword(
       credentialsId: 'artifactory.jenkins.user',
       passwordVariable: 'ARTIFACTORY_PASSWORD',
       usernameVariable: 'ARTIFACTORY_USER')]) {

       sh "uname -a "
       def registry="artifactory:5000"
       def tag="${registry}/hello-world:${BUILD_NUMBER}-shelltest"
       stage('login') {
           sh "docker login ${registry} -u ${ARTIFACTORY_USER} -p ${ARTIFACTORY_PASSWORD}"
       }
       stage('pull and tag') {
           sh "docker pull hello-world"
           sh "docker tag hello-world:latest ${tag}"
       }
       stage('push') {
           sh "docker push ${tag}"
       }
   }
   }
   ```
5. test helloworld on node via artifactory plugin

   ```
   node("docker-experiments") {
   withCredentials([usernamePassword(
       credentialsId: 'artifactory.jenkins.user',
       passwordVariable: 'ARTIFACTORY_PASSWORD',
       usernameVariable: 'ARTIFACTORY_USER')]) {

       def server = Artifactory.server "artifactory01"
       def artDocker = Artifactory.docker(username: ARTIFACTORY_USER, 
                                          password: ARTIFACTORY_PASSWORD)

       def registry="artifactory:5000"
       def tag="${registry}/hello-world:${BUILD_NUMBER}-artifactoryTest"
       def dockerInfo

       stage('pull and tag') {
           sh "docker tag hello-world:latest ${tag}"
       }

       stage('push') {
         dockerInfo = artDocker.push "${tag}", "docker-local"
       }
       stage('publish') {
           server.publishBuildInfo(dockerInfo)
       }
   }
   }
   ```